# debugging methods in android atudio

Tags: android-studio

I started to write code for android. I'm a beginner in this field.

I'm using Android Studio and using the emulator for debugging.
I have a very basic question:
Is there a convenient way to click buttons, write text etc.
in the emulator (like it is done on the device) and set breakpoints inside the callback functions to see the program flow goes there?

right now, something is not working as expected, when I click some button on the device and I want to be able to detect the problem.

Comment: Yes. You can click the buttons in the emulator by clicking on them and set breakpoints inside the callback functions by clicking on the gutter. What is the exact difficulty that you're facing?

Comment: Sounds stupid but I don't see the "physical emulator"... When I click debug I only see the "run" window

Comment: How can I make it visible?

Comment: What is printed there? Note that you can also set breakpoints on an actual device; you don't need to use the emulator for debugging.

Comment: " You can click the buttons in the emulator by clicking on them" - where is the emulator to click. it is not visible to me. how canI configure it to be visible?

Comment: What is printed in the Run toolwindow when you click Debug?

Comment: C:\Users\oshri\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none

Comment: How long did you wait? It's normal that emulator startup takes a long time (even up to a few minutes).